# Making questions in English

Tags: grammar

I have follwing questions regarding English

What are the interrogative forms of the following statements

1. Twenty third CHOGM was held in Sri lanka.(Interrogator needs to know the number)(Please compare (What was held in Sri Lanka ?)Do we have to use any word like when, how, why,...
2. Sam came 2nd in the race.(Interrogator needs to know the number)

Thanks

UB

Comment: Please search the site before asking. The [*frequent* tab under "Questions"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) is a good start. This question has been asked, and answered, 34 times before, and is in our all-time top 15. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Which CHOGM was held in Sri Lanka?
2. In what position did Sam finish the race?

Comment: Not quite so precise, but would usually be OK for number 2 is  "Where did Sam come in the race?"